# Generate Quartz Cron Expression Every 2nd monday/friday

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

How can i generate cron expression for every month 2nd/4th  of monday/friday in quartz.Please help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to create two triggers for the job.

The first trigger for the 2nd Monday:

```
0 0 12 ? 1/1 MON#2 *
```

And the second trigger for the 4th Friday:

```
0 0 12 ? 1/1 FRI#4 *
```

Answer (score 3):

According to [the docs](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/CronExpression.html), you can specify (e.g.) the 2nd Monday of the month by putting `MON#2` or `1#2` in the day-of-week field.

> The '#' character is allowed for the day-of-week field. This character
>   is used to specify "the nth" XXX day of the month.

But composing these like `MON#2,FRI#4` in a single cron expression is specifically prohibited, so you need multiple `CronTrigger`s.